# C loop until 0 is given

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I'm trying to make a loop that lets the user enter numbers one by each other and calculate the sum of all those numbers until the user enters 0 as an input. However, my code is running only once and then stops.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i = 0;
    int num;
    int total = 0;

    printf("Give me a number \n");
    scanf("%d", num);
    
    if(num < 0 && num > 0){
        printf("Give me a number \n");
        scanf("%d", num);
        total = total + num;
        i = i + 1;
    }

    printf("The total is %d", total);
}
```

Comment: can you tell a number that is `< 0` *and* `> 0` ?

Comment: Also, `if` is a branch, not a loop.

Comment: The typical way of making a loop is `for(...)` or `while(...)`. Your code has no loops.

Comment: Could it be that you first tried `num <> 0` à la Pascal?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I think the largest prime fulfills that ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. There are no loops in your code
2. The condition `(num < 0 && num > 0)` is alway false. A number can't be: less than zero **AND** greater than zero
3. Wrong call of `scanf`

You probably want:

```
printf("Give me a number \n");
if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1) exit(1);
while(num != 0){
    total = total + num;
    i = i + 1;
    printf("Give me a number \n");
    if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1) exit(1);
}
```

The above solution will exit the program if the user inputs a non-integer, e.g. a letter.

An alternative solution that will end the loop on non-integer input is:

```
printf("Give me a number \n");
while(scanf("%d", &num) == 1 && num != 0){
    total = total + num;
    i = i + 1;
    printf("Give me a number \n");
}
```

This last solution can even be written a little more compact - like:

```
while(printf("Give me a number \n"), scanf("%d", &num) == 1 && num != 0){
    total = total + num;
    i = i + 1;
}
```

It's a bit harder to read but avoids duplicated lines.

Comment: Thanks, im still learning and couldnt figoure out how to make a loop

Answer (score 3):

This is the idiomatic way IMO. There is only one `scanf` call to scanf and we use `break` to end the loop prematurely if the user has entered 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int i = 0;
  int num;
  int total = 0;

  while (1)          // loop forever
  {
    printf("Give me a number \n");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    if (num == 0)    // if the number is 0
      break;         // we terminate the loop

    total = total + num;
    i = i + 1;
  } 

  printf("You entered %d numbers, the total is %d", i, total);
}
```

Disclaimer:

- for brevity there is no error check for `scanf` which IMO is OK for toy programs.

Otherways the remarks provided by [4386427](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4386427/4386427) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67108504/898348) are correct.

Comment: Agree - using `break` is also a good solution. As I added to my answer, it is possible to do it both without duplicated lines and `break` but that makes the code a bit harder to read. And simple code is often better... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to take the address of the variable (&num) in the scanf() call and add a do{ } while() statement.

```
int main(){
    int i = 0;
    int num;
    int total =0;
    do {
        printf("Give me a number \n");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        total = total + num;
        i = i + 1;
    } while(num != 0);
    printf("The total is %d", total);
}
```

Comment: Oh my, it appears you're the only one who caught the `scanf` problem so far.

Comment: Your solution increments `i` once too many

Comment: @4386427: The original code has `scanf("%d", num);`. But `scanf` requires an address here, as this answer points out.

Comment: @4386427: i is never referenced and hence it can be removed from code. However, i is incremented one times in every loop, not to much.

Comment: @AD1170 If a user inputs "0" your code will set `i` to 1. OP's code will set `i` to 0.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in the if statement you are trying to check if the given number (num) is *at once* greater than 0 and less than 0 which is why the if scope won't be accessed u can use the following if statement
`if(num!=0)`
this will check if the num is different than zero!

and since you are trying to repeat this bloc until 0 is inserted you have to use a while/dowhile instead.

you have also to pay attention to the scanf because you forgot to specify the pointer of the num variable (`scanf("%d", &num);`)

Answer (score 0):

In your case, use of `while (num != 0)` would be more suitable.

```
int main(){
    int i = 0;
    int num = 1;
    int total = -1;
    while (num != 0){
        printf("Give me a number \n");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        total = total + num;
        i = i + 1;
    }
    printf("The total is %d", total);
}
```

Comment: Your solution increments `i` once too many